# Debugging JFrames with array of Buttons

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm having trouble generating an array of buttons for a clone of battleship for my class, and can't seem to figure out why it is not working. Any advice would help... I have the main class creating the jFrame, then the grid class, more specifically the generator method builds the array of buttons.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class warship {

/**
 * @param args
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame gui = new JFrame();
    gui.setSize(700, 350);
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    grid oceanGrid = new grid();
    oceanGrid.Generator();
    gui.add(oceanGrid);
    gui.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

grid.java

```
     import java.awt.Dimension;
     import java.awt.GridLayout;
     import java.awt.LayoutManager;

     import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
     import javax.swing.JButton;
     import javax.swing.JPanel;
     import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


     @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class grid extends JPanel{
private static int rows = 7;
private static int col = 10;

public void Generator(){

    ImageIcon wIcon = new ImageIcon    ("H:\\workspace\\Warship\\src\\images\\water.jpg");
    JPanel jPan1 = new JPanel();
    jPan1.setLayout((LayoutManager) new GridLayout(rows,col,1,1));
    jPan1.setSize(350,350);

    //Set Border 
    TitledBorder bdr = javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Targeting Grid",
            javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION,
            javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION,
            new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 16));
    bdr.setTitleColor(java.awt.Color.RED);
    jPan1.setLayout((LayoutManager) new GridLayout(rows,col,1,1));      
    jPan1.setBorder(bdr);

    //Creates the array of buttons
    JButton b[]=new JButton[rows*col];
    for (int i = 0, j= rows*col; i < j; i++){
        b[i] = new JButton(wIcon);
        b[i].setSize(20, 20);
        b[i].setMaximumSize(new Dimension(20,20));
        b[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
        System.out.println("loop test " + i);
        jPan1.add(b[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what specifically is not working?

Comment: It's not showing any part of the jPanel called by oceanGrid. Not the buttons or the border. But it is running the class because I have a command line print in the for loop for the buttons

Comment: Don't forget to use correct Java naming convention: classes should start with a capital letter and methods and variables with lower-case letters. This becomes important when you ask strangers to help you with your code: code that doesn't adhere to conventions are hard for us to understand making it more difficult to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the mistake you are making:
Your class grid extend `JPanel`, but you declare and initialize another `JPanel` in which you add your buttons. So you are not actually adding the buttons to your grid but to another panel you do not use.

The solution is to remove this line

```
JPanel jPan1 = new JPanel();
```

and to replace all occurences of `jPan1` with `this`

This way you will be adding the buttons to your grid.

Comment: 1+: exactly. The original poster is adding a bunch of components to jPan1, but then throws jPan1 away without doing anything with it. Either add it to the `this` JPanel (and no need to explicitly state `this.`)  or add jPan1 to something.

Comment: Thanks alot I overlooked this.

Comment: ah I missed that in my overview.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing the pack() command right before your setVisible(true).

Comment: Doesn't pack() just auto fit to the size? I'm already setting the size of the gui jFrame. ..... But i tried adding the pack() and it didn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

1 the JPanel in grid is unneeded.
2 the JPanel in grid isn't added to anything using the .add() method.
It seems other people already got to this however.

As said, you should remove the line "JPanel jPan1 = new JPanel();"
and replace the word "jPan1." with the word "this." all lower cases.

Here is a correct indenting of your code edited, or at least one that is easier to read.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class grid extends JPanel{
    private static int rows = 7;
    private static int col = 10;

    public void Generator(){

        ImageIcon wIcon = new ImageIcon ("H:\\workspace\\Warship\\src\\images\\water.jpg");

        this.setLayout((LayoutManager) new GridLayout(rows,col,1,1));
        this.setSize(350,350);

        //Set Border 
        TitledBorder bdr = javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null,         "Targeting Grid",
            javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION,
            javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION,
            new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 16));
        bdr.setTitleColor(java.awt.Color.RED);

        this.setLayout((LayoutManager) new GridLayout(rows,col,1,1));      
        this.setBorder(bdr);

    //Creates the array of buttons
        JButton b[]=new JButton[rows*col];
        for (int i = 0, j= rows*col; i < j; i++){
            b[i] = new JButton(wIcon);
            b[i].setSize(20, 20);
            b[i].setMaximumSize(new Dimension(20,20));
            b[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
            System.out.println("loop test " + i);
                this.add(b[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

do note that anything after this point is just helpful criticism of style at least.

I would have used a constructor in grid so you don't have to call that method. Like this:

```
public Generator(){
    super();

    //code in Generator() here.
}
```

and now you don't need to call the method "Generator()"

and these two lines

```
javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION,
javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION,
```

could be shorter like this.

```
TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION,
TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION,
```